# How to pass and display a JSONArray to GSP page to display?

Tags: grails, gsp

I have a Grails controller that gets a JSONArray that looks like the following:

[image]

So I want to return this JSONArray to a GSP page which would display it (i.e. with each element in the array on a separate table row).

I'm new to Grails so just wondering what my GSP should look like to be able to do this?

Each array element contains a user element with fields such as id, name etc, so I would also like to be able to delete/edit/add users in the GSP page as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly. You can just use a table with g:each for each row. This should work with any arrayList.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
   <th>id</th>
   ...
   ...
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<g:each in="${JSONarray}" var="item">
<tr>
<td> ${item.id}</td>
   ...
   ...
 </tr>
</tbody>
```